# Show first ten characters, expand on click (or hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML snippet which looks like this:

```
<pre>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
    output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
    return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._session = self._make_session()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
    session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
    raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)
</pre>
```

Since most users do not care for the details, I would like to hide the traceback and only show the first few characters.

The remaining text should only be visible if you expand the text.

This should be visible as hyperlink: "Traceback ...."

How to do this with?

(I can't modify the html, a JavaScript/jquery/CSS solution is needed)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution. It's a bit clumsy, but jquery not required

```css
pre {
    width: 10em;
    height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #6c6;
    transition: width 1s ease;
}
pre:hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
    output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
    return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._session = self._make_session()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
    session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
    raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)
</pre>
```

Comment: Works in firefox (Linux) and IE11.

Comment: It's cool CSS magic, guy :) I would append `padding: 5px` to make some space between the text and border.

Answer (score 5):

You could hide the pre's text by adding following CSS / class:

```
.hidden {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

To achive the desired behaviour, you could toggle this class on click.

```
$('pre').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden')
})
```

Here is a working example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvQJxr

Comment: The author said he is not able to change the html. So better add the `hidden` class in `$(document).ready(()=>{ ... })` from JavaScript!

Comment: This might be true for the author - if this is really the case he could add the styles upon document ready. In my point of view, this is however not a clean solution of the problem. Because of this I tried to suggest a more generic solution.

Comment: The question is "How can I do this without touching the html". You solved "How can I do this". Its simply not an answer to the question.

Comment: You're right. However, I do not see a reason for "I can add JS but do not want to touch the HTML". Furthermore is an answer for everyone - not only the author.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. But I still doubt that this is an answer to the given question with the given disclaimer "Cant modify html".

Answer (score 4):

Try using `details` and `summary`. Its very easy and fast to implement.

Also you don't have to handle any click events or css classes or anything else.

Check out this snippet:

```js
let text = $("pre").html()
let header = text.split('\n')[0] // The header is the first line
text = text.substr(header.length); // The text everything besides the first line

// Set the html inside of the pre tag to a details/summary tag combo
$("pre").html(`<details>
    <summary>${header}</summary>
    ${text}
</details>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
    output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
    return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._session = self._make_session()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
    session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
    raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just satisfied below conditions

1. I hide the content in pre tag  and only show the first few
   characters.
2. Remaining text should only be visible if you expand the text.

```css
pre{
 width: 11ch;
 height: 2ch;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 color:blue;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
pre:active{
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color:black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
    output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
    return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
    port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._session = self._make_session()
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
    session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
    raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you already have bootstrap in your project. You might want to utilize the built-in popover :)

Steps:
 1. Hide the traceback (using CSS)
 2. Display the button (plain HTML)
 3. Setup javascript code (JS/JQuery)

Hide the traceback using CSS

```
<style>
    pre{
       display:none;
    }
</style>
<pre>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
        output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
        return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
        return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
        port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
        self._session = self._make_session()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
        session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
        raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
    FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
    Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)
</pre>
```

Somewhere in your HTML, you prepare and display the popover button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" title="The full Traceback">Traceback...</button>
```

Setup the Javascript which would trigger the Bootstrap popover

```
<script>
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      content: $('pre').text().trim()
    });
</script>
```

Advantages:

- You can display any button text that you want. ex: "Display Full Traceback" etc..
- Take advantage of Bootstrap popover options. Ex. You can easily manipulate where you want the popover to display (left, right, bottom, top) For more info, you can go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/
- The flexibility of how you want to handle the "Traceback" data

---

If you don't have Bootstrap, you may want to do a similar approach in pure HTML, CSS, Javascript, and JQuery as well. Here's how...

```
<style>
    pre{
      display:none;
    }

    .full-trace-back{
      width: 500px;
      padding: 20px;      
      background:#fafafa;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
              border-radius: 5px;
    }
</style>

  <pre>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
        output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
        return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
        return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
        port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
        self._session = self._make_session()
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
        session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
        raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
    FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
    Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)
  </pre>

  <script>
    (function () {      
      let isOpen = false;
      $('.trace-back-link').on('click', toggleFullTraceback);

      function toggleFullTraceback() {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
        if (isOpen) {
          const tracebackData = $('pre').text().trim();
          const tracebackLink = $('.trace-back-link');
          tracebackLink.after( "<p class='full-trace-back'>"+tracebackData+"</p>" );
        }else{
          const fullTraceback = $('.full-trace-back');
          fullTraceback.remove();
        }
      }
    }());
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following snippet:

### HTML

```
<pre id="my-content" onclick="ccc(this)" my-attr=``>
    MOJHIT
</pre>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    let content = `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 69, in execute_job_and_create_log
  output = self._execute_job_and_create_log()
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 127, in _execute_job_and_create_log
  return self.execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 133, in execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
  return self._execute_job_and_create_log__ftp()
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/src/foobar/foobar/models/job.py", line 140, in _execute_job_and_create_log__ftp
  port=self.job_group.remote.port, session_factory=SessionOnPort) as host:
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 72, in __init__
  self._session = self._make_session()
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 135, in _make_session
  session = factory(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/foobar_cok_p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 151, in __exit__
  raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
FTPOSError: [Errno 110] Timeout
Debugging info: ftputil 3.4, Python 2.7.13 (linux2)`

    let element = document.getElementById('my-content');
    element.setAttribute('my-attr', content);
    element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute('my-attr').split('\n').join(' ').substr(0,10);
    element.onclick = ccc

    function ccc(event){
        event.target.innerHTML = event.target.getAttribute('my-attr');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It would make it easier to understand if you could create an answer like the other provided. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: The author specifically said that he cant change the HTML code.